# connecting router to router

Tags: wireless-networking, router

my question is this.
our isp has upgraded to fibre broadband and have given us a suitable router so is it possible to connect our old router to the new one through the old way by
by the telephone line so that we can extend the range through the Wi-Fi connection. if there is nice simple directions please as I am not computer literate.
many thanks in advance
adam

Comment: No. You cannot connect the two routers using the telephone line. Your ISP will have disconnected your DSL connection when you were upgraded to fibre. You may be able to chain the routers using an Ethernet cable (but that's a different question).

Comment: We'll need considerably more specifics to be able to help you with this, model numbers, etc. In general tho (if I can decipher what you're asking), if you're old router only has a phone line on the WAN side (DSL modem/router combo), then you're out of luck, but again that's just guessing as you haven't' provided enough information.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question, no. You cannot connect your old router via DSL (telephone cable) if your isp upgraded to fiber optics, the reason is because fiber optics is faster than DLS and your isp probably wishes to give their customers faster internet, you can however connect your old router to your new one (if it supports bridging). Look up "bridging routers" for more information if you wish to bridge.
P.S. make sure both routers support bridging

Comment: I downvoted that because, while the answer to the question is "no" as you stated, the rest of your post is, to be polite, misleading and incorrect.  First off, Fibre is not just faster, its totally incompatible with DSL so the signaling methods are different.  If the current router is, indeed, a DSL route, then you can't bridge the DSL router to the ethernet router using the WAN port, let alone the phone line.

Comment: To support bridging both routers have to be compatible right?

Comment: your questin does not make a lot of sense to me - yes, they need to be compatible, but that is a function of the way data is sent in packets more then anything else. You can bridge different trchnologies/mediums - bridging WIFI with Ethernet is common in home routers, but you can bridge pretty much any carrier of internet data - fibre with ethernet, atm interfaces, even vpns. Bridging is, in effect routing between 2 or more interfaces below the IP layer - ie by routing data packets (in such a way they would be invisible to traceroute for example)